# How to search MongoDB for various phone number formats?

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

I'm attempting to search my MongoDB for string phone numbers that are all in different formats.

E.g. (323)704-3234, 3237043234, 323-704-3234,+1-323-704-3234,323.704.3234, etc.

Is there an operator or regex that I can use that MongoDB provides that allows you to find strings minus special characters?

For example in c#,

```
collection.Find(Query.Matches("PhoneNumber",(some regex, replace, or where)3237043234))
```

Comment: I think it'd be better/easier to update the phone number field in Mongo database after stripping all non-digit characters. Then you'll just have to look for `3237043234` or `13237043234`

Comment: Yep.. that's what I was thinking as well. It looks like there's a case for a $replace operator so it can function like SQL's replace.  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-829

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you are doing it wrong.

You can accept phone strings in any format (if you want so), but before storing them you need to convert them to some specific format. In your case the best will be just to convert it to number (smaller size to store, to create index).

Then one more time, when the user asks for a number - he can also provide it in any format, and before you search for it you will convert it to the number. (Do not forget to put index on phone number field) Being more user friendly, you can show the ouput in the same format the user asked it.

To change all your current phones, just iterate through the database and update each of the numbers.

Comment: I was searching for a solution that wouldn't involve changing the values in the database. Thanks.

Comment: @user1364768 got it. But just to let you know: any solution that you will find will be cumbersome and slow.